# Set property not called for List object

Tags: c#

Could someone help me below?
It seems Set is not called. How can I get around this?

Note that _students is set as the selectedObject of a property grid. So adding is done in the UI.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    List<Student> _students = new List<Students>();

    public List<Student> Students 
    {
        get
        {
            return _students;
        }
        set
        {
            // track changes here...
            MessageBox.Show("value set!"); // this doesn't get called

            _students = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least show the code where you _try_ to call it.

Comment: Are you actually... *setting*... anything?

Comment: This is only the definition of your class. Where is the code that sets Recort.Students = blaBla....

Comment: I actually assign _students instance to selectedObject of a propertyGrid.

Comment: If you assign selectedObject to _students instance, then your commented line Message.Show("ada") is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're having an issue with what `set` does with a list.  You'll never see the message on adding a student to `Record.Students`, only when you set the list.

```
void Main()
{
    Student s = new Student() {
      Name = "fred",
      Age = 10
      };
    List<Student> _s = new List<Student>();
    _s.Add(s);

    Record r = new Record();
    r.Students = _s;  //You'll get a message here
    r.Students.Add(s);  //No message here
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    List<Student> _students = new List<Student>();

    public List<Student> Students 
    {
        get
        {
            return _students;
        }
        set
        {
            // track changes here...
            MessageBox.Show("value set!"); 
            _students = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you just set _students.

If you want that setter to execute, you're gonna have to  go `Students = new List<Student<();` instead of `_students = new List<Student>();`.